# Gradle run/build not displaying Chinese properly

Tags: eclipse, gradle, unicode

Chinese output of Gradle Run is displayed as "????????", while Java Run output is fine.


Output of Gradle run

```
?????
\u5f9e\u51b7\u6c23\u8d77\u6548
?????
```

Output of Java run

```
從冷氣起效
\u5f9e\u51b7\u6c23\u8d77\u6548
從冷氣起效
```

The Gradle project with Eclipse. Chinese output of Java Run can be displayed after setting "Properties" > "Resource" > "Text file encoding" to UTF-8.

Here is the Java code.

```
package testgradle;

import org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String origin = "從冷氣起效";
        String input = "\\u5f9e\\u51b7\\u6c23\\u8d77\\u6548";
        String result = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava("\\u5f9e\\u51b7\\u6c23\\u8d77\\u6548");
        System.out.println(origin);
        System.out.println(input);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

}
```

I have tried to modify build.gradle file, but still the output of Gradle run is not as expected.


build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'java-library'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'testgradle.Test'
    }
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}

application {
    mainClassName = 'testgradle.Test'
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    systemProperty "file.encoding", "UTF-8"
}

javadoc.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.2-jre'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.9'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Please provide solution to solve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you doing to get the "Output of Gradle run"?

Comment: Run this command: gradlew run  That is the console output. @Henry

Comment: Is that inside of Eclipse?

Comment: Tried running command in WIndows cmd and also in Eclipse > "Gradle Task" > "application" > "run". Both display "????" in console. @nitind